# Error: runKubernetesJobAtomicOperationDescription.application.invalid (Must match ^[a-z0-9]+$)

Tags: spinnaker

If you face the same problem as follows:

> runKubernetesJobAtomicOperationDescription.application.invalid (Must match ^[a-z0-9]+$)

Cause: Your spinnaker application name is wrong, for example `sample-application` is a wrong application name. Please remove the hyphen character like this `sampleapplication`.

Answer (score 0):

it's telling you can't have hyphens in your application name as this is used as a separator